# How to change div color when click on another div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, background-color

am new to jquery. i have some colors inside of a div. if i click on any one of color it should affect on another div's background color.i'm getting these colors from database. how to make it?

ex:

```
<?php
  $result = dbclass::convert_array($res);// retrieving colors here
  for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
  { ?>
   <div id="Color" style="background-color:<?php echo $result[$i][1];?>; width:32px;  height:26px;" onclick="changeColor(<?=$result[$i][1];?>)">
  </div>
  <? 
  }
  ?>

  <div id="changableColor" style"background-color:#FFFFFF;"> </div>

function changeColor(newColor)
{
   $(#changableColor) // then how to write?
}
```

i need to change the background color of "id=changableColor".intially it have white background color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 6 lines of your code are extremely hard to read so I rewrote them. You were mixing `<?php` and `<?` which isn't good practice and the style of `for loop` that you should use when switching between `HTML` and `PHP` has been changed, too. A lot of this is preference, though, so feel free to disagree or change it back.

```
<?
$result = dbclass::convert_array($res);
$rows = count($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) :
?>

<div id="Color" 
style="background-color:<? echo $result[$i][1];?>; width:32px; height:26px;" 
onclick="changeColor(<? echo $result[$i][1]; ?>)">
</div>

<? 
endfor;
?> 

function changeColor(newColor) {
    $('#changableColor').css('background-color', '#' + newColor);
}
```

Comment: ya fine....is it correct to i have wrote on onclick...will it pass value into function?? bcoz i didnt get any of values in when i use alert into that function??

Comment: Try it now, I missed the `echo` :P

Comment: In your original code did everything work except the color changing?

Comment: nothing i havent done anything....i just need to change the background value of that div

Comment: ya...i found it..its funny am passing that color variable as a string..so we need to put into ('<? ?>') single quotes..

Comment: While you've fixed the function, this is a bad way to solve the problem. Please see my example for a better way.

Comment: I agree 100% with you Mitch and was in the middle of writing a similar approach

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#changableColor").css("background","#fff");
```

[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BEG9s/1/) is an example

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#changableColor").css("backgroundColor","#colorCode");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of problems in your code. Firstly, inside your for loop you use an ID instead of a class, you should only use an ID once. Secondly, there are better ways to attach this. Please accept below and untested example, it should work, but will need some testing.

```
<?php
    $result = dbclass::convert_array($res); //retrieving colors here
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
?>

<!--  Using class .color instead of ID -->
<div class="color" style="background-color:<?php echo $result[$i][1];?>; width:32px;  height:26px;">
</div>

<? } ?>

<div id="changableColor" style"background-color:#FFFFFF;"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            // Attaching using a jQuery click function
        $(".color").click(function(){
                    // Using this operator to grab the background-color of the clicked item
            $(#changableColor).css("background-color",$(this).css("background-color"))
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please comment if you need further help.